# Python: OS Independent list of available storage devices

Tags: python, cross-platform

Is there a way go get a list of connected storage devices, like Cameras, SD cards and external Hard Drives, in Python?

Comment: How do you define 'storage device'? How 'connected'?

Comment: @Tichodroma The list of external devices that appears in the Mac Finder, Windows Explorer or Ubuntu file browser.

Comment: I wouldn't mind finding internal drives too - so the definition is not so important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work for Linux and Windows. 
This will list ALL drives, not just externals!

```
import subprocess
import sys

#on windows
#Get the fixed drives
#wmic logicaldisk get name,description
if 'win' in sys.platform:
    drivelist = subprocess.Popen('wmic logicaldisk get name,description', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    drivelisto, err = drivelist.communicate()
    driveLines = drivelisto.split('\n')
elif 'linux' in sys.platform:
     listdrives=subprocess.Popen('mount', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     listdrivesout, err=listdrives.communicate()
     for idx,drive in enumerate(filter(None,listdrivesout)):
         listdrivesout[idx]=drive.split()[2]
# guess how it should be on mac os, similar to linux , the mount command should 
# work, but I can't verify it...
elif 'macosx' ...
     do the rest....
```

The above method for Linux is very crude, and will return drives like `sys` and `procfs` etc., if you want something more fine tuned, look into querying with `python-dbus`.

Comment: Probably if you add a step that detects which of the mount points are owned by current user (presumably the desktop logged-in user), the list will be very close to the list of 'external devices'. You should be able to unmount first what you want to unplug.

Comment: here's [an example how to use Udisks via dbus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5081937/4279). Property [DeviceIsRemovable](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/Device.html#Device:DeviceIsRemovable) might be close.

Comment: You can just read /proc/mounts on linux, no need to spawn stuff.