# Is there a system-independent way to find a drive's path by it's label in python

Tags: python, cross-platform, removable-storage

Using python, I would like to find the path to a drive by it's label on all platforms (linux,windows,mac), for example I would like to search for the drive named STUFF and get the path (e:/ or /media/patrick/e/ ) back or an error if it does not exist.

Comment: What have you found by searching? There seem to be a number of solutions for windows and linux.

Comment: @PeterWood I have found ways to find a label by the drive name but not the other way around

Comment: If you do that for each drive you have a solution.

Comment: @PeterWood But how can I get an os-independent list of drives?

Comment: See [hopeful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672981/python-os-independent-list-of-available-storage-devices) and [not hopeful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596485/python-cross-platform-way-to-list-disk-drives-on-linux-windows-and-mac)